# osx sed regex match only spaces before search term

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Say my search term is CAT, replace term is DOG
I only want to match things that begin with whitespace before CAT, regardless of how much whitespace. Also, is there any way I can preserve the correct amount of whitespace?

so

```
else CAT {
```

would stay

```
else CAT {
```

but

```
CAT {
```

would become

```
DOG {
```

and

```
                  CAT {
```

would become

```
                  DOG {
```

I am trying `sed -i ' ' -E "s/^[^a-z]*CAT/DOG/g" $file` so that it doesn't match anything that has letters anywhere between the beginning of the line, and the search term

And other variations, but haven't found anything that works correctly. I can't do `sed -i ' ' -E "s/^[ \t]*CAT/DOG/g" $file` because `\t` doesn't work on OSX

---- my file:

```
method()
{   
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        hello1
    }

    else if ((self = [super init])) {
        hello2
    }
}
```

---- using `sed -i '' "s/^\([[:blank:]]*\)$s/\1$r/" $file`

Turns it into:

```
method()
{   
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        hello1
    }


    if () {
        hello2
    }
}
```

which is bad, because I don't want the second else if to be affected at all. The first one is good though.

Comment: You say "which is bad..." at the end but you're missing the most important parts which is to show us what is good output and the regexp stored in `$s` that you are trying to find and replacement in `$r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [character class](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) with capture group as

```
sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]*\)CAT/\1DOG/'
```

- `\([[:blank:]]*\)` Matches zero or more white spaces and capture them in group 1, `\1`.

---

**Example**

```
$ echo "                  CAT {" | sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]*\)CAT/\1DOG/'
                  DOG {
```

Comment: I should mention that I'm actually searching for variables, so CAT is $CAT. This isn't finding and replacing anything in my file. Can that be why? I also tried with double quotes.

Comment: @user101 `$` has to be escaped as it has a special meaning to sed (end of pattern space): use `\$`

Comment: @BenjaminW. Not required if you are using double quotes.

Comment: @user101 I tried something like `sed "s/^\([[:blank:]]*\)$test/\1DOG/"` which seems working on OSX. with `test=CAT`

Comment: Ah, I might have misunderstood: either OP wants to replace `$CAT` with `$DOG` literally (`$` has to be escaped), or they want to use a shell variable in the sed command (can't use single quotes anyway).

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Still not working for me :( I've edited my post with the exact file and variables so you can try to replicate

Comment: Never surround a script with double quotes, always single. If you need to make part of the script accessible to the shell for interpretation, do it locally not globally, e.g. given a variable `cost="$50"` when you want to change the price in your file use `sed 's/'"$cost"'/$25/'`, not `sed "s/$cost/$25/"` to avoid surprises when you forget to escape characters (as I just did deliberately) and other issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing group for whitespaces:

```
sed -i ' ' -E 's/^([[:blank:]]*)CAT/\1DOG/' file
```

There is no need to use `g` flag since we are replacing at the start only once.

If you want to use variables then use double quotes:

```
s='CAT'
r='DOG'
sed -i '' -E "s/^([[:blank:]]*)$s/\1$r/" file
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear from your question but maybe this is what you want:

```
$ cat tst.sh
old='if ((self = [super init])) {'
awk -v old="$old" '
BEGIN {
    new = old
    gsub(/.*\(|\).*/,"",new)
    new = new ";"
}
start=index($0,old) {
    before = substr($0,1,start-1)
    after  = substr($0,start+length(old))
    if (before ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/) {
        $0 = before new after
    }
}
{ print }
' file

$ ./tst.sh
method()
{
    self = [super init];
        hello1
    }

    else if ((self = [super init])) {
        hello2
    }
}
```

Note that you can just construct the replacement text on the fly and because its using literal strings instead of regexp and backreference-enabled-string operations you don't need to escape anything in either the string you are searching for or its replacement (except backslashes - we can tweak that to fix if you need it).

If you had been considering using sed for this or using *sub() or match() in awk then read [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) first.